# Modify json object from file and keep structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

We have a json with object like following

**JSON Before**

```
// comment 1
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "type": "task1",
        "script": "watch",
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
        "isBackground": true,
        "presentation": {
            "aaa": "never"
        }
    }]
}
// comment 2
```

**JSON After**

Now I want to add a new object a new task (task 2)

```
// comment 1
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
            "type": "task1",
            "script": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "aaa": "never"
            }
        },

        {
            "type": "task2",
            "script": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsh",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "aaa": "never"
            }
        }
    ]
}

// comment 2
```

The trick here, that I need to update the object **without** changing the structure, lines or comment. I try with jsonParse and it doesnt works

Is it possible in javascript/nodejs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking out the [comment-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/comment-json) package, this is what it is designed to do, you shouldn't need to roll your own for this.

You can parse the JSON, then add the new task and write to your new file:

```
const { parse, stringify} = require("comment-json");
const fs = require("fs");

const taskFile = parse(fs.readFileSync("./input.json", "utf8"));

let taskToAdd = {
  "type": "task2",
  "script": "watch",
  "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
  "isBackground": true,
  "presentation": {
      "aaa": "never" 
  }
};

taskFile.tasks.push(taskToAdd);
fs.writeFileSync("./output.json", stringify(taskFile, null, 4));
```

**input.json**

```
// comment 1
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "type": "task1",
        "script": "watch",
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
        "isBackground": true,
        "presentation": {
            "aaa": "never"
        }
    }]
}
// comment 2
```

Of course, if you wish to modify the JSON file in place, simply set the input and output filenames to the same value.